# URL rewrite htaccess my website

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I would like to be able to access this URL on my website:

www.mysite.com/author/username

trough this one

www.mysite.com/username

Please consider that people should be able to access using the two url and that the "username" always change depending on the user.

What would be the best way to do it? htaccess rewrite?

Thank for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it could be messy and box you in if your users create names that match paths that overlap with existing or future paths.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z]+$    #1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f     #2
RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+)$ /author/$1 [P]  #3
```

1. try to restrict it as much as possible to your username pattern
2. only rewrite if the path doesn't already exist
3. proxy to the /author/username version of the URL